# Google Analytics show zero for "Search Engine Optimizations" graph

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics new design, there is an area related to the queries and impressions related to your site. You can get there by following **Traffic Sources** => **Search Engine Optimization** => **Queries**.

[image]

However, it now shows zero for the "Site Usage" graph, at the top section, while other areas of Google Analytics definitely show that site has visitors and has been used.

[image]

No matter how much I search, I can't find the source of the problem. Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: Do you see any 'No data is available from the most recent 2 calendar days' type notification above the graph?

Comment: Yeah, but it says for **2** days, not for **4** days. That's why I think something's wrong. You see 4 zero dots in my graph.

Comment: Doesn't the SEO data come from your linked webmaster tools account? (which google seems to update as they please, ie. irregularly). Add this to the 2-day notification and you may get your 4 days. Not sure otherwise, hence this being a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, the data comes from webmaster tools, and I've linked webmasters and analytics together. I don't know about update policy however, and really, Google doesn't seem to be a lazy company.

Comment: Is it possible your Webmasters account got unlinked?

Comment: Or that your snippet got deleted?

Answer (score 2):

The "Search Engine Optimization" graph pulls data from your Google Webmaster Tools account.   For some reason this data often takes Google several days to process.  For me, it has gotten several days behind, but then always caught up eventually.

The interface often says "There is no data for the last 2 calendar days."  It appears that it sometimes says this even when there is no data for a longer period of time.

[image: Google Analytics No data is available from the most recent 2 calendar days]

If you are missing data for a week or more, check to make sure that your GWT account is still connected to your Google Analytics account.  You can do this through GWT:

[image: Google Webmaster Tools connect to Analytics]